# Qbittorrent leaking, or plain user error?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, bittorrent

I was torrenting open-source software, and received a DMCA email (which was bogus). I always keep a VPN on when I surf the web, but I had just updated OpenVPN and my qBittorrent client was not downloading anything.

So I went to advanced and set the network interface from OpenVPN Wintun to "any interface." Does this mean that even when my VPN was on, that the torrent client could use my straight wifi to download torrents?

I used ipconfig /all and checked my connections, and only two were in play, a LAN Tap-Windows adapter and a Wireless LAN adapter Wi-fi, the rest saying "media disconnected". The network interface list on qBittorrent showed:

> 

- any interface
- local area connection
- OpenVPN Wintun
- OpenVPN Data Channel Offload
- local area connection* 2
- local area connection* 3
- Wi-fi
- Bluetooth
- loopback pseudo-interface 1

> 

I now have it connected to local area connection, which is downloading. Is this the right setting?

Comment: “Is this the right setting?” - Only if your local area connections is connected to the VPN you intend to use. Improperly configured VPN or even a VPN server that leaks information about your connection what prevents DCMA strikes, legitimate or illegitimate.